# Alamofire Dark Sky API request Swift

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to make complete a .get request for the dark sky API which requires the following parameters to complete the request:      https://api.darksky.net/forecast/[key]/[latitude],[longitude]

My code looks like the following and I am getting an 'extra argument in 'method' call which I think is because my function data types are wrong. I have been trying to play around and search for the correct ones but I can't get it right.

My Alamofire request is as follows:

```
//Get wind data method

func getWindData(url: String, key: Any, latitude: Any, longitude: Any) {

    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, key, latitude, longitude).responseJSON {

        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {

            print("Success! Got the weather data")
            let windJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            print(windJSON)

        }

        else {
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))") }
            self.yard.text = "Connection issues"
    }

}
```

and my 'Did update method' is as follows to use the phone gps to get the required latitude and longitude of the user:

```
//Did update method
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
    if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        print("latitude = \(location.coordinate.latitude), longitude = \(location.coordinate.longitude)")

        let latitude = String(location.coordinate.latitude)
        let longitude = String(location.coordinate.longitude)

        getWindData(url: base_URL, key: api_Key, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

    }
}


//Did fail with error method
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
    print(error)
    yard.text = "Error"
}
```

Many thanks in advance! Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
 let openWeatherMapBaseURL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/Key_Here/"
 let urlStr = "\(openWeatherMapBaseURL)\(latitude),\(longitude)" 
 Alamofire.request(urlStr, method: .get, parameters:nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { [weak self] response in
 }
```

There is no extistence for

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, key, latitude, longitude).responseJSON
```

parameters of get need to be in url , also `latitude` and `longitude` are `double` values not `Any`

Comment: what's the current problem ?

Comment: My code is:

func getWindData(url: String, latitude: Double, longitude: Double) {
        
        let base_URL = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/122f0903268466d1d2db69d187484837/"
        let urlStr = "\(base_URL)\(latitude),\(longitude)"
        Alamofire.request(urlStr, method: .get, parameters:nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { [weak self]
            
            response in
            if response.result.isSuccess {
                
                print("Success! Got the weather data")
                let windJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

Comment: func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        let location = locations[locations.count - 1]
        if location.horizontalAccuracy > 0 {
        self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
          
            let latitude = String(location.coordinate.latitude)
            let longitude = String(location.coordinate.longitude)
            
            getWindData(url: base_URL, latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)

Comment: get rid of url parameter no need for it as you hardcode the url inside the function ?, this seems ok for me , does it work with you ?

Comment: it works now, thanks so much for your help! I changed the function to as follows: func getWindData(latitude: String, longitude: String) and called the function as follows: getWindData(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude) and it then printed in my debug area. I tried it with type 'double' but that didn't work as it wanted 'string' thanks again!